# Reload Image if Image fails to load via Component Slot

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, nuxt.js

So we have class project for this image component loader which tells the user if the image is loading, loaded and error on load.

```
<ImageLoader> 
  <img slot="image" :src="iamge.path" />
    <div slot="preloader" >
      <p>Image is loading!</p>
    </div>
    <div slot="error"> 
      <p>Error! Image Didn't load</p>
    </div>
</ImageLoader>
```

The Componenet itself is:

```
<template>
    <div class="load-image">
        <slot v-if="status === 'loaded'" name="image" />
        <slot v-else-if="status ==='failed'" name="error"/>
        <slot v-else-if="status ==='loading'" name='preloader'/>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
const Status = {
    PENDING: "pending",
    LOADING: "loading",
    LOADED: "loaded",
    FAILED: "failed"
}


export default {
    data: () => ({
        status: null,
        img: null,
        src: null,
    }),
    created() {
        const { attrs } = this.$slots.image[0].data;
        this.src = attrs.src || attrs["data.src"];
        if(this.src) {
            this.status = Status.LOADING;
            this.crossOrigin = attrs.crossorigin;
            this.createLoader();
            return;
        }
        if(this.src === undefined) {
            this.status = Status.FAILED
            return;
        }
        this.status = Status.PENDING;
    },
    updated() {
        const { attrs } = this.$slots.image[0].data;
        const receivedSrc = attrs.src || attrs["data.src"];
        if(this.status === Status.LOADING && !this.img) {
            this.createLoader();
            return;
        }
        if(this.src !== receivedSrc) {
            this.src = receivedSrc;
            this.crossOrigin = attrs.crossorigin;
            this.createLoader()
        }
    },
    watch: {
        src(value) {
            this.status = value ? Status.LOADING : Status.Pending;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        createLoader() {
            this.destroyLoader();
            this.img= new Image();
            this.img.onload = this.handleLoad;
            this.img.onerror = this.handleError;
            this.img.crossOrigin = this.crossOrigin;
            this.img.src = this.src;
        },
        destroyLoader() {
            if (this.img){
                this.img.onload = null;
                this.img.onerror = null;
                this.img = null
            }
        },
        handleLoad() {
            this.destroyLoader();
            this.status =   Status.LOADED;
            this.$emit("onLoad");
        },
        handleError(error) {
            this.destroyLoader();
            this.status = Status.FAILED;
            this.$emit("onError", error);
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

We are planning to put a "Reload this image" button inside the error slot. However,
How would we go about reloading the image when the image fails to load? Do we reload the whole component? Or is there a technique there is we are missing out on?

Comment: You can use `v-bind:key` to a variable that changes value, that forces the component to be reloaded: [v2](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) and [v3](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#key) docs

Comment: So I can just assign the component to a new random number when the user presses image reload button and then the component itself will reload and re-fetch the image, yes?